# How to express this into a double summation format

Tags: summation, summation-method

Suppose, I am having difficulties writing down as double summation. The expression is $$b_1(t_n)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^1 {a_{1k}u_k}+b_2(t_n)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^2 {a_{2k}u_k}+ ... +b_p(t_n)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^p {a_{pk}u_k}$$

It's probably pretty simple(with a less than/condition in a summation) but can't come up with the correct one.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^p\left(b_n(t)\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}u_k\right)$$

Comment: Use `\cdots` instead of three periods to get a properly spaced and vertically centred ellipsis.

Comment: @Abezhiko, shouldn't we expand the inside summution first? If yes, the solution doesn't correspond to the expression after expanding. If we should expand the outer summation, it is good.

Comment: The outer one always comes first when dealing with non-commutative sums (because the second sum depends on the index of the first one), in the same manner as for double integrals; thus, it has to be understood as $\sum_{n=1}^pb_n(t)s_n$, with $s_n$ being defined as a sum itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we see that the upper indices $1,\ldots,p$ of the sums correspond to the indices $j, 1 \leq j \leq p$ of the factors $b_j\left(t_n\right)$ and $a_{jk}$. We can therefore write
\begin{align*}
b_1(t_n)\sum_{k = 1}^1 {a_{1k}u_k}+b_2(t_n)\sum_{k = 1}^2 {a_{2k}u_k}+ \cdots+b_p(t_n)\sum_{k = 1}^p {a_{pk}u_k}
=\sum_{\color{blue}{j}=1}^pb_\color{blue}{j}(t_n)\sum_{k = 1}^{\color{blue}{j}} {a_{\color{blue}{j}k}u_k}
\end{align*}